# Random Errors In Android App

Tags: android, audiotrack

I have three synthesizer applications at:

[https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Red+Venice+Apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Red%20Venice%20Apps)

They works perfectly for me on a usb connected mobile phone, under multiple android studio emulators but occasionally under user deployment crashes with illegalstateexceptions or nullpointerexceptions or tgKill.

Ive managed to handle most of these problems with overidden onTrimMemory(), using the ComponentCallbacks2 interface and with System.GC() placed strategically on memory hogging code. My crash reports are not minimal but still not as perfect as I would like.

The synthesizer itself can create up to six oscillators at frequencies based on the XY access of the touch screen.

Each oscillator creates a waveform object(sawtooth, square, sine, triangle) using the standard Audiotrack sound synthesis process.

On the main activity I handle the motion events but stopping, starting and flushing the Audiotrack on each movement.

Any ideas of further memory optimizations I could try?